# Dispatching an action in a debounced function using redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the following debounced function that gets called every time a user inputs into the username field. It is working as expected.

```
export const uniqueUsernameCheck = _.debounce(({ username }) => {
  axios.post(`${API_URL}/signup/usernamecheck`, { username })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Is unique?', res.data.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, 500);
```

However using redux-thunk I am trying to modify the function so that I can dispatch actions within my function. This is what I have:

```
export const uniqueUsernameCheck = _.debounce(({ username }) => {
  console.log('I can see this');
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('But not this');
    dispatch({ type: USERNAME_CHECK });
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/signup/usernamecheck`, { username })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(authError(res.data.error));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}, 500);
```

The problem lies in that the above code no longer fires off my post request like the initial function did and nothing ever gets dispatched. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

EDIT:

This is how I've set up my store

`const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egeOyJ

```
const userService = _.debounce(username => {
  setTimeout(
    ()=>{
      console.log('userService called after debounce. username:', username)
    }
    ,1000)
}, 500)

const uniqueUsernameCheck = (username) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('I can see this')
  userService(username)
}

console.log('begin')
const reducers = (action) => {console.log(action)}
const store = Redux.createStore(
  reducers, 
  {}, 
  Redux.applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk.default))

store.dispatch(uniqueUsernameCheck('rafael'))
store.dispatch(uniqueUsernameCheck('rafael'))
store.dispatch(uniqueUsernameCheck('rafael'))
```

Comment: Two considerations: you must dispatch a function that receives 'dispatch' directly; you must create the debounce function only once.